# Join and batch update in LINQ to SQL

Tags: linq

Can something like this be written in LINQ to SQL:

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET CustomerName = t2.Name 
FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.TableID = t2.TableID
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var result =  from t1 in context.Table1
              join t2 in context.Table2 on t1.TableID = t2.TableID
              select new {t1, t2};

result.ToList().ForEach(i => i.t1.CustomerName = i.t2.Name);
context.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: But in this case the SQL server is running multiple update statements. Behind the scene LINQ is creating multiple update statements on the SQL server. The original query that I have written in SP is just 1 query and not mulitple update statements.